# Capturar ID dinámico con su archivo

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

Hola desarrolladores buenos días, mi problema es el siguente:

Estoy desarrollando un aplicativo .NET con MVC y razor y en mi codigo html tengo un ciclo for que me genera unos div con un formulario correspondiente a lo que tengo en base de datos ejemplo si tengo 10 en bbdd me genera 10 div con su respectivo id dinámico (id="@lista.iddocumento" que tengo que capturar) ese div tambien tiene un browser en el cual tengo que cargar ese archivo y he intentado capturar ese id de todas maneras posibles (jquery y javascript) y no logro que me muestre la alerta con su id para yo saber que sí se pudo capturar, la idea es que si hago click en "X" upload me carge ese archivo y me seleccione específicamente ese id:

mi codigo html:

```
 @if (ViewBag.ListaDocumentos != null)
            {
                var LstDoc = (List<WebAppSpeed.Models.LicenciaInterna>)ViewBag.ListaDocumentos;

                for (int i = 0; i < LstDoc.Count; i++)
                {
                    string id_documento = Convert.ToString(LstDoc[i].Id_documento);
                    //string contador = Convert.ToString(i+1);
                    if (@LstDoc[i].Carga_vigencia == "S")
                    {
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                                        <h4 class="font-weight-medium" style="margin-bottom: 15px; line-height: 20px;">
                                            <i class="far fa-file-alt"></i> @LstDoc[i].Descripcion_documento

                                        </h4>
                                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 30px;">
                                            <label for="exampleInputCity1">Vigencia de documento</label>
                                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputCity1" placeholder="01/01/2019" style="width: 60%;">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                <div class="estatus" style="display: inline; margin-top: 0px;">
                                    <div style="margin-right: 20px; display: inline;">
                                        Estatus: <img src="~/Images/estatus_malo.svg" width="10px;">
                                        <p class="estado-malo">Malo</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="display: inline;">
                                        Nombre archivo: <label class="preview-archivo" for="inputGroupFile01" data-id-documento=@LstDoc[i].Id_documento
                                                               id="labelInput">Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" onclick="window.open('ebook.pdf')" class="text-small-izq">
                                <div class="mas-info-izq"><i class="far fa-eye"></i> Preview</div>
                            </a>
                            <a class="text-small-der">
                                <label class="mas-info-der text-small-der" for="inputGroupFile01" style="margin: 0px;">
                                    <span class="far fa-folder" id="@id_documento"></span> Upload
                                </label>
                                <input type="file" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01"
                                       style="visibility: hidden;">
                            </a>

                    }
}
```

mi código js (que no funciona) antes me generaba la alerta pero como undefined y ahora nisiquiera me genera una alerta simplemente no manda el id cuando hago click:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body #seleccion_documento').on('click', 'span', function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id'))
    })
var id_doc = this.attr('id')
    })

</script>
// y ya capturando el id tendría que mandar el archivo al controlador (archivo y id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deduzco que en esta parte del código quieres hacer click y saber el Id. Puedes crear una función, en este caso `mostrarId()` y pasarla al evento onclick del `<span>` pasándole como parámetro el @id_documento.

```
<label class="mas-info-der text-small-der" for="inputGroupFile01" style="margin: 0px;">
     <span class="far fa-folder" id="@id_documento" onclick="mostrarId(@id_documento)" >
    </span> Upload</label>
    <script>
    function mostrarId(id){
    alert(id);
    }
    </script>
```